# Poistive part of a closed operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been struggling with the following: If $T$ is a densely defined closed operator, then $T^*T$ i self-adjoint and positive and so we set $|T|=\sqrt{T^*T}$. I further assume here that $T$ is symmetric but not self-adjoint.

My question: I would like to see a proof why $T+|T|$ is not closed. The best I have obtained, is that $T+|T|$ is symmetric. In fact, it is essentially self-adjoint by a famous theorem by Wust (a weaker version of Kato-Rellich). So a way to get round this problem is to show that $T+|T|$ is not self-adjoint. Any help is most welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Math

Comment: Any comment or help?

Comment: Is this question that hard?